# Failed to decrypt AES encrypted file by Javascript using OpenSSL

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

The ciphertext is encrypted by Javascript using the AES algorithm in hexadecimal format. I first coded it in Base64 and then decrypted it using OpenSSL.

But it failed, I don't know where it is wrong.

And I am using a Windows compiled version of OpenSSL.
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm

The command is as follows:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -A -in Cipherbase64.txt -out PlainText.txt -K 31323334353637383930303030303030 -iv 31323334353637383930303030303030 -d
```

result:

```
bad decrypt
6396:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:./crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:461:
```

Ciphertext (HEX)

```
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
```

Thanks to Topaco for your help. Because of my negligence, mistake CTR for CBC, causing confusion.

Comment: But the OpenSSL document writes; `-a
This means that if encryption is taking place the data is base64 encoded after encryption. If decryption is set then the input data is base64 decoded before being decrypted.`

Comment: I get the same error after replacing `-a` with `-base64`. Is the problem on the JavaScript encryption algorithm? I am not sure if the Javascript algorithm it uses is compliant with the AES standard. I have not given the Javascript algorithm part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -A -in Cipherbase64.txt -out PlainText.txt -K 31323334353637383930303030303030 -iv 31323334353637383930303030303030 -d
```

After the `-K` and `-iv` options, the input must be a hexadecimal string, i.e. instead of `1234567890000000` you have to use `31323334353637383930303030303030`. The `-A` option says that the Base64-encoded ciphertext is contained in one single line, [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-enc.html). So there is no need to use line breaks.

**Update:**

It turned out that the JavaScript-[code](https://filebin.net/k96dolsetwreu8es) *actually* applied to generate the posted ciphertext uses [CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR))-mode for encryption (instead of [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_(CBC))-mode). Therefore, the OpenSSL-statement which can be used to decrypt the posted ciphertext is:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-ctr -a -A -in Cipherbase64.txt -out PlainText.txt -K 31323334353637383930303030303030 -iv 31323334353637383930303030303030 -d
```

The decrypted text is:

```
{"sign":"13adab9285fe86206b73e029ff0d290fc0e31237","timestamp":1570608017,"logid":"MTU3MDYwODA2MjAzMjAuMTMzMjE0Nzc2OTIxNTgxNDY=","uk":3012946979,"shareid":547370362,"fid_list":"[\"482622974717034\"]","input":"aaxb","vcode":"33324238656332346361663334656637323237633636373637643239666664336662393132313032313738303030303030303030303030303031353730363038303530B0D6C0036A1909217D2CDCD5B76B46FB"}
```

which can be easily verified [here](https://cryptii.com/pipes/aes-encryption).

Comment: You are right. It is necessary to convert 1234567890000000 to HEX. But I still got a bad decrypt error. I am using a Windows version of OpenSSL. http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm I don't think this is an opensl error, I am also sure that there is no error in converting HEX ciphertext to Base64. So I am confused, why I can't get the expected results.

Comment: Is it wrong on the padding? Is OpenSSL using PKCS#5 instead of PKCS#7 by default?

Comment: I think a padding-problem is rather unlikely. For the difference between Pkcs5- and Pkcs7-Padding see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding). Did you use the `-a -A` options? If not, this will result in `bad decrypt`.

Comment: If the issue still persists: Your CryptoJS-code returns the ciphertext as a hexadecimal string. The OpenSSL-statement expects a Base64-encoded ciphertext in the `Cipherbase64.txt` file. Have you considered this? So that we refer to the same example: Please use your code and key and IV to encrypt the following plaintext (without an ending dot) _The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog_ and post the result in both, hexadecimal- and Base64-encoding, the latter corresponding to the content of the `Cipherbase64.txt` file.

Comment: The [openSSL version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL#Major_version_releases) used (0.9.8h) seems to be relatively old, but there are no indications yet to suspect the issue here.

Comment: Although "Crypto" in the original code was replaced by "le.a", I am sure that the algorithm used is crypto-js. Although crypto-js has multiple branches, I think the algorithm should follow the AES standard. Since this js comes from other sites, I can't get it to encrypt custom plain text.Yes, I don't doubt this is a problem with the OpenSSL version, I use other encryption and decryption of custom text, it works fine.

Comment: Yes, PKCS#5 and PKCS#7 are used interchangeably and are not the problem.

Comment: It seems as if it's not quite clear which code on the other side is used for encryption. If so, it will be difficult to solve the problem because decryption depends on encryption. However, if you are reasonably sure that the posted CryptoJS-code is being used, you could simulate encryption with that (= the posted) code, e.g. at https://repl.it/languages/nodejs. Depending on whether decryption is successful with your OpenSSL-variant, the error can be narrowed down accordingly.

Comment: This is the JS code and should contain the full AES encryption algorithm. https://filebin.net/8dzqmkn41bym009f I have added a partial fragment of the call to the encryption function.

Comment: I've checked the posted ciphertext. It can't be encrypted with the posted CryptoJS-code because it can't be decrypted with the parameters used there (AES-128/CBC/PKCS7/key/IV). This applies generally, no matter if OpenSSL or CryptoJS which can also easily be verified with https://cryptii.com/pipes/aes-encryption. In addition, the linked JS-code also uses other algorithms and modes that may have been used for encryption. You must first determine the algorithm/mode/padding/key/IV of the encryption from the sender side, otherwise decryption is hardly possible.

Comment: https://filebin.net/k96dolsetwreu8es This is the full JS source code. The data to be encrypted is on the client and then sent to the server via js encryption. The algorithm/mode/padding/key/IV is all in JS. Although the site has updated JS, the algorithm should still be the same. I really don't understand why OpenSSL can't decrypt it.

Comment: https://cryptii.com/pipes/aes-encryption The webpage decrypted it successfully! Thank you ! I will use the OpenSSL test during the day, good night!

Comment: This code uses CTR-mode instead of CBC-mode. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: When I posted this question, I re-acquired the encrypted data, but I didn't realize that the JS code has been modified at this time, that is, "mode: le.a.mode.CBC" has become "mode: de. a.mode.CTR", but I still use the old JS, I am sorry for the trouble caused by this, this is completely my negligence.And thank you very much for your patience, I may not find the answer without your help. The OpenSSL I use does not support aes-128-ctr . But I changed to another compiled version, it works perfectly. Thank you again!